# Unable to get user company information on microsoft graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having a problem with Microsoft Graph API... Currently I have a web application that has an openid integration with Microsoft/Azure using the common v2 endpoint.

We are trying to get the signed in user company name and job information. The official docs say that we need to make a request to the MS Graph API.

We are testing it on Microft Graph Explorer but it doesn't seem to work.

We've selected the 'User.Read' as a permission in our app, then tried these endpoints:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=companyName,jobTitle
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$select=companyName,jobTitle
```

In MS offical doc (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference) on User/Remarks sections, it clearly says that 
`"On reads, only a limited number of properties are returned by default. To read properties that are not in the default set, use $select"`

Is this doc outdated? 
I've tried to reach MS support for developers, but they answered saying that I should ask this on Stack Overflow...
So probably there are no official support for developers?
Is it really possible to get the company name and job title from a MS account?

Thanks in advance!

edit. Update question with MS graph explorer screenshots
[image]
[image]

edit.2. Update screenshot with proper encoding.

Also, it's a MS account not an Azure account, since our web app accepts both of them on the common v2 endpoint.

**Update**

My goal was trying to get the `Work Info` section from a MSA account.
[image]

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? I tested using the default account on the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/?$select=companyName,jobTitle` gave me good results, even though `companyName` was `null` (because it is).

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Actually, there are no errors... 
When trying to query on `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/?$select=companyName,job‌​Title` I just receive the same response as `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`, without the company name or job title (my account has both of those information)

Comment: Can you show a quick screenshot? Make sure to hide any sensitive information.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi I've updated the question with the screenshots

Comment: I am able to reproduce your error using an MSA account. It is working for me with AAD accounts.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Oh sorry! Yes, this is a MSA account. I didn't tested it with an AAD account yet. Since our web app supports both accounts with the common v2 endpoint, we need to extract the company and job information (if present) on both accounts.

MSA accounts have a different endpoint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation is correct, by default we only return a subset of [user properties](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user#properties):

- id
- userPrincipalName
- displayName
- givenName
- surname
- jobTitle
- mail
- mobilePhone
- businessPhones
- officeLocation
- preferredLanguage

If you want a different set of properties, you can request them using the `$select` query parameter. The queries you provided in your question should work fine. For example, when I execute `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=companyName` in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) (after logging in with my credentials) I get the following:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(companyName)/$entity",
    "companyName": "MICROSOFT"
}
```

**Update Regarding MSA**

When using Microsoft Graph against a Microsoft Account (MSA) there are several differences in what properties get surfaced. As an MSA is by definition a personal/individual account, organizational properties such as Job Title and Office Location are simply not applicable.

Comment: I've updated the question with screenshots, even with the `$select` params my graph explorer response is the same as the `/me` endpoint.

Comment: This looks like an UTF encoding issue. Are you by chance pasting this into the text box? If you look at the results it is showing `job%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BTitle` rather than `jobTitle`.

Comment: Sorry, I did paste it but this isn't the root of the problem. I've updated again the question with a proper encoding screenshot.

As pointed out by @Shawn Tabrizi, this is a MSA account not an AAD account.

Comment: Okay, if this is an MSA than several properties won't be available. MSA's are personal accounts and therefore do not include any company information.

Comment: Oh I see, so I can't get the profile's "Work Info" section?

Comment: That is correct. This is admittedly very confusing but there are a lot of "profiles" tied to an MSA. Keep in mind that these accounts have been migrated, merged and amended many times over the years (Hotmail, Passport, Live, MSA, Outlook.com). The profile information available is pulled from the https://account.microsoft.com site. Note that "Work Info" isn't part of this account, that is part of the old https://profile.live.com and isn't available via Graph.

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=companyName Works as expected